# Test flight : This build is no longer available. Couldn't load the app

Tags: app-store-connect, ios11, testflight

iOS 11, Test flight: I have expired Latest app from the test flight. In my iPhone, now I m getting this error.

Couldn't load the app. This build is no longer available. There is no option to select the previous build.